# how does the diagram for this statement look like in multithreading

Tags: multithreading, caching, architecture, cpu-cores

I have come across this statement and I am wondering how it should be interpreted, please be patient with me thank you.

"Given a multi core system Pr1 and Pr2. The addresses Add1 and Add2 are mapped to the same cache block but A1 is not equal to A2. The cache state is initially invalid."

Would the cache blocks and processor look like the diagram I have drawn in A or in B? I'm confused about what it means when Add1 and Add2 are mapped to the same cache but does that mean that Pr1 and Pr2 access the same single block? Or do they each have their own blocks ?

[image: My interpretation]

I came across this diagram hence why I am confused how the architecture in this statement looks like.

[image: architecture image]

Any kind explanation is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Think of a cache as a bounded hash table, as used by software. The addresses are hashed to the same location and that causes a collision.

- A direct mapped cache maps to a array element (replacing on collision)
- A set-associative cache will have a fixed sized list at the array slot (replacing the LRU within the list)
- A fully-associative cache is a open addressed hash table (LRU across all elements).

In your example the cache starts out as empty (invalid blocks). When loading the memory location the two addresses map to the same cache line. If we assume direct mapped cache then the loads conflict, causing the other item to be evicted when loaded into the block. This conflict could be a performance problem by causing thrashing if both are hot entries being frequently used, thereby causing stalls due to memory fetches. An associative cache would support some collisions, e.g. 2-way might be enough in practice to avoid this problem in most cases. This might mean that a L1 direct mapped + 2-way L2 may be acceptable, where the per-core cache suffers from collisions but the shared cache does not and the penalty to main memory is avoided.

Comment: thank you! so does that mean that the 2 processors have access to the same cache line? If Processor1 wrote data to Add1, and Processor 2 tried to write data to Add1 that was previously modified by Processor 1, does that mean that the cache for Processor 1 would be marked as 'invalid' and the dirty bit for processor 2 would be active? :)

Comment: @MeganDarcy I believe in that case the cache [coherence protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) because they do not share a cache tier, but do need to maintain data consistency. When P1 invalidated a block then it would broadcast a notification so that P2 invalidated it. My naivety here is that the an associativity conflict would not be of concern as it would check by address, so a write to A1 would not directly invalidate A2. However, [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) would mean that if A1 and A2 both fit in a cache line then their writes conflict.